# Perforce CLI hangs indefinitely

Tags: perforce

Surprizing little documentation on setting this up, so I'm sure this is a setup problem.

Steps to reproduce:
Open terminal (p4.exe in PATH)
type p4 [RET]

Hangs indefinitely.  When I issue commands from emacs (ie p4 edit [file] it eventually comes back with

```
Perforce client error:
 Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
 TCP connect to perforce failed.
 perforce: host unknown.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message that is displayed when called from emacs points in the right direction, p4 can't find your perforce server (the default is `perforce`, that's where the `perforce: host unknown` comes from.

Make sure to either specify `-p` for your call to p4 or set the environment variable `P4PORT`. Beware, despite the name, P4PORT includes the hostname of the perforce server.

`p4 -p serverhost:1666`

I'm not sure why p4 would hang indefinitely on the CLI and return after some time when called from emacs.

Comment: The actual problem was that .perforce needs to be in your home directory and I was pointing to 5550 instead of 1666

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set these variables in order to get it to work (very annoying it just hangs instead of complaining of the missing configuration).

P4PORT
P4USER
P4CONFIG
P4EDITOR

Answer (score 0):

Please check if a p4 process running in background in the same shell. you need to stop already running process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30024604)